# Which is best way to search for multiple values in multiple tables in grails? Plugin or dynamic finders?

Tags: grails

I'm using dynamic finders to search, but when I search for fields in other tables there is an error.
This is my action

```
def searchResults ={
 if (request.method == 'POST') {
 def criteria = Incident.createCriteria()

 def results = criteria {
 and {
   like('status', '%' + params.status + '%')
   like('severity', '%' + params.severity + '%')
   assignmentGroup {
    like('groupId', '%' + params.assignmentGroup + '%')   
   }
  }

    }
   render(view:'list', model:[ incidentInstanceList: results ])
   }
```

This is my view where I let the user select values:

```
   <g:form action="searchResults" controller="incident">
    <div class="dialog">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="prop">
                <td valign="top" class="name">
                    <label for="status"><g:message code="incident.status.label" default="Status" /></label>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: incidentInstance, field: 'status', 'errors')}">
                    <g:select name="status" from="${incidentInstance.constraints.status.inList}"
                              value="${incidentInstance?.status}" valueMessagePrefix="incident.status" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="prop">
                <td valign="top" class="name">
                    <label for="severity"><g:message code="incident.severity.label" default="Severity" /></label>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: incidentInstance, field: 'severity', 'errors')}">
                    <g:select name="severity" from="${incidentInstance.constraints.severity.inList}"
                              value="${incidentInstance?.severity}" valueMessagePrefix="incident.severity" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="prop">
                <td valign="top" class="name">
                    <label for="assignmentGroup"><g:message code="incident.assignmentGroup.label"
                                                            default="Assignment Group" /></label>
                </td>
                <td valign="top"
                    class="value ${hasErrors(bean: incidentInstance, field: 'assignmentGroup', 'errors')}">
                    <g:select id="groupSelect" name="assignmentGroup.id" from="${app.Usergroup.list()}" optionKey="id"
                              value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <span class="button"><g:submitButton name="searchResults" class="searchResults" value="searchResults" /></span>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

For the first two values it is working fine.  But with the `assignmentGroup` there is an error.

```
Error 500: Executing action [searchResults] of controller [app.IncidentController] caused exception:
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of app.Usergroup.id
```

Incident class:

```
   package app
   class Incident {
      Usergroup assignmentGroup
      User assignId
      String severity
      String status


  static constraints = {

    servity(inList:["low","high"])
    status(inList:["Open","Closed","WIP"])
    createdOn()
    assignmentGroup()
}

}
```

Usergroup class:

```
 package app

 class Usergroup {

 String groupId

    static hasMany = [members : User]
    static belongsTo = User 

    static mapping = {
    table "group_" 
    }

    static constraints = {
     groupId(blank:false)
   }
   String toString (){ groupId }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the DomainModels involved?  It isn't clear from your example what the fields are part of.

Comment: sure...i've tagged the domain classes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try criteria something like that:

```
def results = criteria {
  and {
    like('status', '%' + params.status + '%')
    like('severity', '%' + params.severity + '%')
    assignmentGroup {
      like('groupId', '%' + params.assignmentGroup + '%')   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 500: Executing action [searchResults] of controller [app.IncidentController] caused exception: No such property: results for class: app.IncidentController Possible solutions: request

Comment: ok, update your searchResults action, I will see. There might be parentheses mismatch..

Comment: Well, you missed last closing parentheses, but if u didn't then there is no chance to get the mentioned exception.

Comment: an empty list is retrieved..should change something in list view

Comment: obviously your criteria not matching. Print parameters and see all the parameters are coming, check results by adding criteria parameters one by one and see which one is causing problem or not matching ..

Comment: when i use only status and severity,its working well and fine.when add assignmentGroup empty list retrieved..

Comment: Check values you stored into db for `groupId` in User domain class and `params.assignmentGroup`

Comment: still the problem not resolved.i have checked the values its properly getting stored into database.can you tell me any other alternative way using like,java class?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using 'like' for the assignmentGroup. I would
try something like...

```
def results = criteria {
                like('status', '%' + params.status + '%')
                like('servity', '%' + params.servity + '%')
                eq('assignmentGroup', params.assignmentGroup)

    }
```

Christian

Comment: Error 500: Executing action [searchResults] of controller [app.IncidentController] caused exception: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of app.Usergroup.id